# How to add device aibs to kernel configuration file?

Tags: kernel, asus

I have an asus laptop, which I have installed in Ubuntu 18.04, Everything works fine but the fans. They make a lot of noise and work always in maximum speed. So I have tried to work this out using pwmConfig, but sensors command does not show any fan. The solution to that is to add device aibs driver to the kernel configuration file or place this line "aibs_load="YES" in loader.conf file as mentioned here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man4/aibs.4freebsd.html.
My problem is I didn't figure out how to do either of the two methods.
How To compile this driver into the kernel? Or how to load the driver as a module at boot time ?

Comment: I do not think this driver is included in linux. Your reference is for freebsd.